# AngularFireList is not assignable to type 'Observable<Response>

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I have an Ionic page which is querying FirebaseListObservable to make dynamic searching on ion-searchbar. It works well with Angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.0 and firebase@4.5.0.
After upgrading new release [AngularFire 5.0](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#upgrading-to-angularfire-50) I get an issue about FirabaseListObservable has no exported from new Api.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage,  NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-modal-groups',
  templateUrl: 'modal-groups.html'
})
export class ModalGroupsPage {

  groups: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(public navParams: NavParams,
    public viewCtrl:ViewController,
    public afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  getItems = (ev: any) : Observable<Response> =>  {
    
    this.groups =  this.afDatabase.list('/Groups', {
       query:{
         orderByChild: 'namelower',
         startAt: (ev.target.value),
         endAt: (ev.target.value + '\uf8ff')
       }
      }
     );


     return this.groups;
  }

  chooseGroups(item:any){
      
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(item); 
    // console.log(this.product);
  }

  closeModal(){
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(); 
  }

}
```

```html
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Grup Seç</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="closeModal()" >
        Kapat
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


  <ion-content padding>
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item  *ngFor="let item of groups | async" (click)="chooseGroups(item)">
      {{ item.name }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <!--<button ion-item  *ngFor="let item of products | async" (click)="chooseProduct(item)">
  {{item.name}}
</button>-->
</ion-content>
```

Then I changed the query with new api but I can not return response as an observable as you see below. Im getting error like this

**message: 'Type 'Observable[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
  Type 'AngularFireAction[]' is not assignable to type 'Response'.
    Property 'type' is missing in type 'AngularFireAction[]'.'
**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage,  NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireAction} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
/**
 * Generated class for the ModalGroupsPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-modal-groups',
  templateUrl: 'modal-groups.html',
})
export class ModalGroupsPage {

  

  items: Observable<AngularFireAction<firebase.database.DataSnapshot>[]>;
  group: BehaviorSubject<any>;

  constructor(public navParams: NavParams,
    public viewCtrl:ViewController,
    public afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  

  getItems = (ev: any) : Observable<Response> =>  {
    this.group = new BehaviorSubject(ev);

    this.items = this.group.switchMap(name =>
    
      this.afDatabase.list('/Groups', ref => name ? ref.orderByChild('namelower').startAt(ev.target.value).endAt(ev.target.value + '\uf8ff') : ref
   
     ).snapshotChanges());
  

     return this.items;
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to get `Observable<Response>` from AngularFireList from **5.0** onwards,
use `valueChanges()` function.

Check the change [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#50).

```
return this.afDatabase.list('/Groups', {
       query:{
         orderByChild: 'namelower',
         startAt: (ev.target.value),
         endAt: (ev.target.value + '\uf8ff')
       }
      }
     ).valueChanges();
```

If you want to save an instance of `this.afDatabase.list()` in `this.groups`, it will be [`AngularFireList`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#updating-firebaselistobservable-to-angularfirelistt) instead of `FirebaseListObservable`.

Comment: changing this.afDatabase.list() to this.afDatabase.list<Item>() fixed my issue. Thanks for the link to the doc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.valueChanges()` as shown below.Here is the [**doc**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#50).

```
  groups: AngularFireList<any>;

  constructor(){}

getItems = (ev: any) : AngularFireList<any> {
  this.groups =  this.afDatabase.list('/Groups', {
       query:{
         orderByChild: 'namelower',
         startAt: (ev.target.value),
         endAt: (ev.target.value + '\uf8ff')
       }
      }
     ).valueChanges();

    return this.groups;
}
```

Comment: Damn ninja'd..:p

Comment: Hehe `1 min` delay :D @SurajRao

Comment: Although you may have to change the declaration type of `this.groups` if I am not wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Angular 5.0 is refactor of AngularFireDatabase,it remove FirebaseListObservable and FirebaseObjectObservable

FirebaseListObservable ====> AngularFireList
FirebaseObjectObservable====>AngularFireObject

you can follow  [link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md)

Answer (score 0):

In Angularfire2 5.0 or higher, if you need observable list with a query you have to use **AngularFireAction** as you see below

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavParams, ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireAction} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {EmptyObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/EmptyObservable';
// import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-modal-groups',
  templateUrl: 'modal-groups.html',
})
export class ModalGroupsPage {

  
  groups: Observable<AngularFireAction<firebase.database.DataSnapshot>[]>;

  

  constructor(public navParams: NavParams,
    public viewCtrl:ViewController,
    public afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

 -

  getItems = (ev: any) : Observable<AngularFireAction<firebase.database.DataSnapshot>[]> => {
    if(!ev.data){
      return this.groups = new EmptyObservable();
    }
    this.groups =  this.afDatabase.list('/Groups', ref => ref.orderByChild('namelower').startAt(ev.target.value).endAt(ev.target.value + '\uf8ff')).valueChanges();
    // this.groups = this.groupsRef.valueChanges();
      return this.groups;
  }

  chooseGroups(item:any){
    // this.product.push({key:item.$key, name:item.name, price:item.price, quantity:1 });
      
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(item); 
    // console.log(this.product);
  }

  closeModal(){
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(); 
  }

}
```

Answer (score -5):

I installed the following versions of angularfire2 and firebase:

```
npm install  angularfire2@4.0.0-rc0 firebase --save
```